# Valores minimo y maximo en un campo en SQL server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Como indico el valor máximo y mínimo de un campo tipo int en la base de datos.

He intentado con este código, pero no me funciona.

```
Sexo char(1) CHECK (Sexo IN ('F','M')) //Funciona
Nota_Practica int NOT NULL CHECK (Nota_Practica > 0 && Nota_Practica < 60), //no funciona
Nota_Parcial int NOT NULL CHECK (Nota_Parcial > 0 && Nota_Parcial < 40), //no funciona
Nota_Final int DEFAULT (Nota_Practica + Nota_Parcial)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supongo que estas creando la tabla.

```
Nota_Practica int NOT NULL CHECK (Nota_Practica > 0 AND Nota_Practica < 60),
Nota_Parcial int NOT NULL CHECK (Nota_Parcial > 0 AND Nota_Parcial < 40),
```

Fijate que use `And` en lugar de `&&`

Comment: en el caso de || debes usar OR.
En el ejemplo no lo dice, pero complementa a tu respuesta.

Comment: Me recomiendas que utilize un stored Procedure.

Comment: @Jesse siempre es preferible que uses procedimientos almacenados, al formular una query desde código, te arriesgas a ser víctima de SQL injection.

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta @gbianchi